# Using document.ready in requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I making use of several requireJS modules in my application. There are few modules(independent of each other) in which I want to do certain operations when the document is ready.

So can I use jquery's document.ready inside my modules. Is it a bad practice. Will using document.ready in requireJS modules will cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) explains it very well:

"*It is possible when using RequireJS to load scripts quickly enough that they complete before the DOM is ready. Any work that tries to interact with the DOM should wait for the DOM to be ready. For modern browsers, this is done by waiting for the DOMContentLoaded event.*"

But for older browsers that don't support `DOMContentLoaded`, you can download the given module and do this:

```
require(['domReady!'], function (doc) {
    //This function is called once the DOM is ready,
    //notice the value for 'domReady!' is the current
    //document.
});
```

So just use the facilities provided by `require.js` rather than JQuery.